# Existence of multiple optimal solutions in Linear Programming simplex method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

Let us suppose the final iteration of the simplex tableau indicates nondegeneracy (no basic variable is at zero level) and the reduced cost of one of the non-basic variables is zero. Are we *always* *guaranteed* to have another optimal solution that is distinct from the current optimal solution in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just as long as the initial optimal point is basic feasible, as this is because the optimal solution for that type of model doesn't exist on just a singular point, but on a  line with an infinitely amount of points. Let's consider the model:

$$\max\quad z=2000x_1+3000x_2$$
Subject to:
$$6x_1+9x_2\le100$$
$$2x_1+x_2\le20$$
$$x_1,x_2\ge0$$

Now let's graphically depict this without the objective function as such:

[image]

What we'll find is that when we solve this is that the objective function will envelop the entire line like so:

[image]

Simplex is landing at either upper-corner, optimal extreme points in the model, and the non-basic variable that would produce the other optimal solution is the variable that correlates with the opposite optimal point that lives on the optimal line (the non-basic variable with a reduced cost coefficient of zero). In actuality, all points that exist on this line are optimal to this model, thus we can represent optimal lines as such:

$$\lambda(x_1,y_1)+(1-\lambda)(x_2,y_2),\quad\lambda\in[0,1]$$
where points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are unique extreme points on either end of the line. Thus, this is why we are always guaranteed to have another optimal feasible point if we pivot in the multi-solution situation if we start pivoting from an already feasible optimal point.

Comment: Can we have a case where in the optimal simplex table one if the non basic variables has a reduced cost of 0 and has a column with all non positive entries making it a case of unbounded problem? Can we have both cases simultaneously?